# .NET: Move control according to rectangle

Tags: .net, location, size, controls, setbounds

I would like to place a control at the location and with the size of a rectangle.

I tried it like this:

```
Me.RichTextBox1.SetBounds(myRectangle)
```

However, there is no overloaded SetBounds that accept a rectangle.
That really confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the bounds of the control instead:

```
Me.RichTextBox1.Bounds = myRectangle
```